# Question is closed as duplicate but there's no link to the duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

The title says it all. This is the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/725770/1065197

Here's an image showing what I'm saying:

[image: dup with no dup]

I guess this an odd bug that applies for old questions only. Anyway, I would want to check which was the question posted as duplicate.

Comment: See the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/725770/revisions) for the post. It was marked as a duplicate of 3 different posts.

Comment: @Antony good point, didn't notice it. Anyway, usually a question closed as duplicate provides the links in the title, and this question doesn't. That's why I raised the post here.

Comment: This post is so old. The way the system handles duplicate has changed a lot since then.

Comment: @Antony yes, that's covered in the last sentence of my question.

Comment: I find this quite amusing, since the question doesn't actually duplicate any of the linked questions (except maybe the deleted one).

Answer (score 6):

It was closed on:

> occurred Apr 7 '09 at 15:36

Which was *way* before the code was changed to edit the duplicate into the body of the question - let alone before the recent(ish) change that put it as a notice.

Comment: Yes, I think the convention was to manually edit the links into the body of the question back then, which led to this being automated later. This is a highly subjective question, so I'm contemplating just deleting it. I note that the [most highly upvoted original](http://stackoverflow.com/q/132777/1288) has already been deleted.