# This question is marked as duplicate but of which?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions

Recently, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13539131/4932070) which is marked as duplicate of another question, but I don't see it.

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

We don't see the link to the duplicate question at the top of the question like this one here.

[image]

Is this a bug or something I am not aware of?

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269091/4932070) tells that a duplicate note is inserted in the post. **The post mentioned in the linked question is gone now.**

However, it wasn't present in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13539131/4932070), so it created the confusion and nobody really checks the revision history to find the duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322505/comma-separated-string-to-array

The problem is in how the system worked back when the question was marked as a duplicate. These days, the system adds a box outside of the question text itself, like in your second example. Back in 2012, when the question was marked as a duplicate, the system edited the duplicate notice *into the question itself*. This meant that, just like anything else in the question, ordinary users could edit it.

Fast-forward to 2014, when a user (who was presumably trying to be helpful) thought it was incorrect clutter and removed the duplicate notice. That user commented,

> No Array magick is needed. strpos(',' . $list . ',', ',' . $item . ',') !== FALSE; is enough. And so this is not a duplicate.

The problem is that the user's edit didn't reopen the question or even count as a vote to do so. It just made the question confusing, as you've pointed out.

See the post revision history [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13539131/revisions).

I went ahead and reclosed it properly.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know that it was inserted in the post as a notice. And since it was removed, it created confusion. Nobody really checks the revision history when they come across the question.

Comment: @AbhishekAggrawal That's a fair point; most people don't check that history. I wasn't involved in the decision to change the way the system indicates duplicates (I don't work for SO), but I'm guessing that this scenario is the major reason for the change.